# How to Display 1 record of DataBase in 1 row of asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

multi field in each line and multi lint in 1 row ,instead all field in 1 row
for example:

`id    name    family


description    date`

instead:

`id    name    family   description    date`

Comment: Orginizationl DB Structure: Database -> **Table -> Record ->** Field

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with GridView. You would have to use a Repeater. Here's an [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the listView over the repeater depending on what version of .net you have.
[ListView](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/The_ListView_Dominates_The_Repeater.aspx)